# Not able to access files in the bin folder after setting PATH variable

Tags: linux, unix

I have added HADOOP_INSTALL and it's bin to the PATH variable in my .bash_profile (shown below) and executed it using the command `. .bash_profile`. I can run the command `hadoop version` fine but when I close the terminal and run the same command again it gives me error as follows

```
gsidevas@gsidev-cloudvm ~]$ hadoop version
bash: hadoop: command not found
```

## Current .bash_profile

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH
```

What do I need to do so that this HADOOP_INSTALL and it's bin gets set permanently in my environment?

Comment: What shell and distro are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, BASH reads and executes commands in .bash_profile only in login shells. If you're creating a terminal via some X11 or similar software, chances are that terminal is *not* a login shell by default.

You can achieve this effect for *every* shell by simply moving the changes you made into your .bashrc file. Please note that this only works properly if your username on the system uses "bash" as its shell and not "sh" since for "sh" the .bashrc file is, by default, ignored.

Comment: I moved the changes to .bashrc and it worked ! Thanks :)